# Python Anaconda: ImportError undefined symbol: ATL_cpttrsm

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, importerror, anaconda

```
>>> import scipy.stats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 334, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 186, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 22, in <module>
    from scipy import optimize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py", line 165, in <module>
    from ._root import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_root.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import nonlin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/nonlin.py", line 122, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse.linalg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from .dsolve import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .linsolve import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _superlu
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlu.so: undefined symbol: ATL_cpttrsm
```

Importing scipy.stats gives the error above. I recently installed Python anaconda. I have tried reinstalling numpy and scipy but to no avail. I am using **Ubuntu 14.04**

The command "which -a python" gives the following lines as output :-

```
 /home/abhishek/anaconda/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You don't happen to have `$PYTHONPATH` set, do you?

Comment: My $PYTHONPATH is :/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. Is there another python path for Anaconda installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unset `PYTHONPATH`. It is causing your Anaconda Python to pick up packages installed in /usr/local instead of just the Anaconda packages (which should work correctly).

Comment: Thanks your solution is more generic than mine.

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out to me that the scipy installation in /usr/local/ was broken and that I needed to uninstall it.

```
sudo pip uninstall scipy
```

This fixed the problem.